# query on urdf.xacro file

Tags: rviz, urdf, xacro, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What are the different file types that can be converted to for a .STEP file to make it readable(mesh) in a urdf.xacro file? other than .stl and ogre.mesh

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10177/query-on-urdf.xacro-file/) by [ram](https://answers.ros.org/users/641/ram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2011-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK, you can use three different types of mesh here:

- .dae  (Collada)
- .mesh (Ogre)
- .stl

I just used FreeCAD to convert the STEP file into a STL file, and it worked great.

The meshes you specify in the URDF are used in a number of places, such as visualization in RViz, and collision avoidance.

It would be great to have some documentation about the "officially supported" mesh types in the wiki. At the moment, this information is scattered across a number of pages:

- [RViz Mesh Resource Marker](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Mesh_Resource_.28MESH_RESOURCE.3D10.29_.5B1.1.2B-.5D)
- [URDF XML reference](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/XML/Link#line-67)
- [URDF tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch#line-231)

Perhaps somebody with more insight into this can have a look?

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3